# what method for nanobot to control human body without affecting the brain?

Tags: science-in-society, nanotechnology

i mean controling the external body like limb and such without internally going into human brain or mindcontrol using nanobot, or going inside human skin or nerve (contact with skin is fine but not something like going inside muscle or skin etc).

so the person is controlled like puppet but still conscious or aware.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: you want to use nanobots without  having them in or on the controlled body?

Comment: without interfacing brain-, nerve-, or muscle tissue that is pretty much impossible. you could encase the whole human in a thick shell of nanobots, but what would be the point?

Comment: yeah but i mean its fine on the controlled body or externally though

Comment: hence i want to know the possibility

Comment: controlling the nerve or skin or muscle is fine what i mean is the nanobot is not inside the controlled body but like human suit or something

Comment: You need to expand your story greatly. A nanobot is tiny so we have to assume you are using millions of them. Not entering the body really defeats the whole point of nanobots. Where and what is controlling the nanobots?

Comment: on the skin like a suit

Comment: So you’re looking for a nanobot-based suit of armor that’s not controlled by the wearer, but instead takes commands from someone else? The feasibility of that will depend entirely on what your nanobots are capable of and how they interact. Without more comprehensive information, I’m afraid we won’t be able to give you a best answer so I’ve voted to temporarily place your question on hold as “unclear what you’re asking”

Comment: Are you thinking of something like a [tens unit](https://youtu.be/n5V6BNpJuH0?t=65)?

Comment: @CortAmmon yeah that seems like what i mean thanks

Comment: @Dubukay well for capability first most it can control human body but externally, the rest is no restriction just assume the nanobot can do what it can do like creating electrical field for example. i dont know what you mean with the "interact" though, are you mean nanobot with nanobot or the body?

Comment: @Thorne the nanobot is self aware so no "someone control it" the ai or the nanobot control themself. something like venom from marvel but a nanobot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control of the muscles of a human body is limited if one remains outside of the body.  We do have some limited ability to do so using electric fields, such as those produced by [TENS units](https://youtu.be/n5V6BNpJuH0?t=65).  These can cause a muscle to contract.

However, such contractions yield very little control.  Our muscles are organized into muscle units, which are small groups of fibers within a muscle that always contract together.  Our [bicep](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2465192/) has about 53 of them, and we recruit them in various orders to have fine control over our motion.  If one is using TENS style electrical fields, it's hard to affect them one at a time -- you tend to contract the whole muscle.  An individual being controlled in this way would be jerky, like a zombie.

To get a sense of what it would be like, consider playing [QWOP](http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html), a game which challenges you to run by controlling the leg muscles directly.