# Is there other similar/better method like TENS units for external control of human muscles?

Tags: science-based, medical, cyborg

*This question inspired by an answer to [my previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150939/what-method-for-nanobot-to-control-human-body-without-affecting-the-brain)*

My goal is to identify an external device that can be attached to a person to puppet the person's body.

A [TENS units](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5V6BNpJuH0&feature=youtu.be&t=65) can cause a muscle to contract. It can be used as an outside-the-body way to control of the muscles of a human body.

> However, such contractions yield very little control. Our muscles are
>   organized into muscle units, which are small groups of fibers within a
>   muscle that always contract together. Our bicep has about 53 of them,
>   and we recruit them in various orders to have fine control over our
>   motion. If one is using TENS style electrical fields, it's hard to
>   affect them one at a time -- you tend to contract the whole muscle. An
>   individual being controlled in this way would be jerky, like a zombie.
>
> To get a sense of what it would be like, consider playing QWOP, a game
>   which challenges you to run by controlling the leg muscles directly.

Is there another similar/better method like TENS units or a solution to make it to affect muscle groups one at a time rather than whole muscle?

Any method/stuff that goes inside the body is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Bicep**s** with an "s"; it means "two-headed" in Latin. The muscle is called two-headed because it is divided into two branches with separate insertion points on the scapula.  There is also a [triceps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triceps) muscle and a [quadriceps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadriceps_femoris_muscle) muscle.

Comment: A transgenic strain of Cordyceps, maybe.

Comment: @AlexP Acceptable use of singular "bicep" entered English dictionaries in 1939 according to my web searches. I looked because I was editing the question and deciding whether to fix this or not. I've decided -- because this is both a quote of another answer and because of the acceptable usage -- to let it stand.

Comment: I really like this question, as soon as I can I'll add an answer to it :)

Comment: The plural of *biceps* is *bicipes*, by the way. (iirc)

Comment: @SRM-ReinstateMonica wow...thanks for the bounty, if you want to give it to specific user just tell me, since its yours after all, and i dont know much about bounty or how to reward it to someone, so if i acidentally wasted it iam sorry.

Comment: @lijun it is mine to grant in a few days to whatever I think is the best answer. You still get to mark the answer you think is best.

Comment: @SRM-ReinstateMonica ah... is that so, sorry for the misunderstanding, i dont know much about how bounty work.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could do this using magnetic stimulation of neurons. The magnetic field induces an electrical potential in the neuron which actives the neurons and it can work from (small) distance without requiring electrodes on the body.

Current devices are pretty coarse and can only affect moderately large areas of the brain  either by activating or passivating them with the magnetic field ([transcranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation)). However theoretically you could create a device that is accurate and strong enough to stimulate individual motor nerves or small areas of the motor cortex to trigger desired motor functions.

Answer (score 2):

Remember cordyceps? That fungus that causes ants to go mad? It was initially thought that it affected their nervous system, but it has been discovered recently that cordyceps leaves ants' neurons intact. It attaches directly to muscle, which is even creepier.

So you don't want an invasive method. Imagine if you will a fungus that grows outside the body, on the skin. This is the staple of medicine, athlete's foot is a thing... Speaking of which, athlete's foot causes an itch. With some varieties, it is a very annoying, very strong itch that is worse than searing pain or a laser to the eye in terms of screwing up your ability to concentrate on anything.

Develop a fungus like that, that can stimulate the skin with pinpoint precision. Only instead of causing itch, cause pain. That will cause a local contraction! Fungus are able to do so, as they are able to create structures that are able to pierce materials much harder than the human skin. You just want to break the outer layer though, not pierce through the skin.

As for how you control the fungus: cover your victim in armor which can deliver chemicals in the inside. Mimic the signals of the fungus and you can control it. This armor will also provide the moist, dark environment that makes the fungus feel comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically speaking a device placed at the base of the skull or where the nervous system begins? It would need to have incredibly fast processing and be capable of redirecting the electrical signals you brain sends to your muscles. Or initiate those signals remotely considering that if you are trying to control someone it would be easily foiled if they simply decided to do nothing so that nothing would be there to redirect. If a is device is capable of producing electric signals in the nervous system of the body however it seems plausible.